# Why DC potential at output of diiferential amplifier limits output voltage swing (peak to peak)?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier

Why DC potential at the output of differential amplifier (or any amplifier) limits peak to peak voltage swing?I have read that because of direct coupling, dc level increases and this tend to shift the operating point of succeeding stage and therefore limit the output voltage swing and may even distort the output signal.Why this happen?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here.  A DC potential at the output of an amplifier is due to the input being amplified or to some external source forcing the output.  Not sure how you want to relate those things to limiting the peak to peak voltage swing.  Maybe you could re-word the question?

Answer (score 1):

What you read was probably talking about an amplifier circuit with a single-ended supply and directly-coupled output. Such circuits can't produce outputs outside the supply voltage range. So if the positive supply is \$V_{ss}\$ and the negative supply is \$V_{ee}\$ and the dc voltage of the output is \$V_{odc}\$, then the maximum output amplitude is

$$\mathrm{min}\left\{V_{ss}-V_{odc}, V_{odc}-V_{ee}\right\}$$

And for if the amplfiier does not have rail-to-rail output capability, the maximum amplitude will be even smaller.

Then in order to maximize the available you should choose

$$V_{odc}=\frac{V_{ss}-V_{ee}}{2}$$

with some slight adjustment if the outputs aren't rail-to-rail and the required margins are not equal on either side.